# how to substitute equals sign for the word EQUALS using sed

Tags: csv, sed, replace

Using `sed`, im trying to replace the `=` character with the word `EQUALS` when `=` is within the value of a `key=value` pair (comma delimited).  Such as:

```
DE1=this,DE2=hsajdusus,DE3=8jashn&dsjud=wkqaihwe8,DE4=yes,
```

In this instance:

```
DE3=8jashn&dsjud=wkqaihwe8
```

should be:

```
DE3=8jashn&dsjudEQUALSwkqaihwe8
```

The `=` character would always show up in the "DE3" key, which can be in any position within the record.

Ive been trying:

```
sed ':a;N;$!ba;/DE3/,/,/s/=/EQUALS/2'
```

with no luck.

such as hold key "DE3" thru , then replace second instance of `=` with "EQUALS"

ideas?

Answer (score 2):

You can try this `sed`

```
$ sed -E 's/(=[^=,]*)=/\1EQUALS/g' input_file
DE1=this,DE2=hsajdusus,DE3=8jashn&dsjudEQUALSwkqaihwe8,DE4=yes,
```